# How to use sql definitions in python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am new to python. I need to use definitions for SQL in the execute function. I can use normal SQL in the function but not any col format or definitions. It gives error as invalid sql. I am able to execute normal sql without definitions. But if i add definitions which is used in oracle sqlplus, then execute function is not parsing it similar to sqlplus.

**Code:**

```
dbcur.execute("def sysmetcol='METRIC_NAME,round(VALUE) TOTAL_PERCENT'"
                  "def sysmetwhere='METRIC_NAME IN ('Database CPU Time Ratio','Database Wait Time 
                  Ratio') and INTSIZE_CSEC=maxsec'"
                  "def sysmetview='v$sysmetric'"
            """
                WITH csec as(
                            select max(INTSIZE_CSEC) as maxsec from SYS.V_$SYSMETRIC
                            )
                select &sysmetcol
                    from &sysmetview,csec
                where &sysmetwhere
                    order by METRIC_NAME
            """
    )
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pltrt.py", line 37, in <module>
    dbcur.execute(query)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Comment: What are these *definitions*? Oracle doesn't have any *definitions* in [SQL reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/)

Comment: These are custom definitions which are used in oracle sqlplus, similar to variable declaration. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm

Comment: SQL\*Plus is a client tool. It is not a SQL. You need to inject this text into SQL statement using Python string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm), `DEFINE` is a command used with the SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer) user interface that defines a substitution variable that will be processed entirely by the local SQL*Plus client. When the client has processed the substitution variable (effectively by performing a find-replace action) then the resulting SQL text is passed to the server.

- The SQL engine on the database server does **NOT** see the original query text or the substitution variable.
- The SQL engine on the database server does **NOT** understand the `DEFINE` command (because it is a command for the client application and not for the database).
- The SQL engine does **NOT** know what substitution variables are or know how to process them (in static SQL queries; in an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement it treats the substitution variable syntax as an alternate syntax for bind variables but it still does not understand the `DEFINE` SQL*Plus command and bind variables are different to substitution variables).

If you want to use the equivalent of substitution variables then pre-process the SQL text in Python and find all occurrences of each substitution variable identifier and replace it with the replacement text.